# Oracle Reports Comparing Database Timestamp to Current Timestamp

Tags: oracle, timestamp, oraclereports

I'm attempting to write a BeforeReport Trigger that checks to see if a user is accessing report data within 120 seconds of creation.

My code is as follows:

```
function BeforeReport return boolean is

ENTRYDATE TIMESTAMP;
SERVERDATE TIMESTAMP;
DIFFSECONDS NUMBER;
begin

/*Checks to see if user is accessing the data within 120 seconds of creation in database*/
VALIDTIMELENGTH := 120;
SELECT SYS_DATE INTO ENTRYDATE FROM WOS_REPORT_PARAM WHERE SEQUENCE_NUM=UPPER(:SEQUENCENUM) AND PARAMETER='year';
SERVERDATE := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
DIFFSECONDS := ((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ENTRYDATE)- EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SERVERDATE))*31536000) +
             ((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ENTRYDATE)- EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SERVERDATE))*2592000) +
             ((EXTRACT(DAY FROM ENTRYDATE) - EXTRACT(DAY FROM SERVERDATE))*86400) +
             ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ENTRYDATE) - EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SERVERDATE))*3600) +
             ((EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ENTRYDATE) - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM SERVERDATE))*60) +
             (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ENTRYDATE) - EXTRACT(SECOND FROM SERVERDATE));
  IF DIFFSECONDS > VALIDTIMELENGTH THEN RETURN(FALSE);
  ELSE
  return (TRUE);
  END IF;
  END;
```

The problem is, my code seems to return true regardless of how much time has gone by. Am I not implementing my seconds/minutes code correctly? Oddly enough , I experimented with making both returns (FALSE) and it still proceeded to pass the report! Oracle Reports is so inconsistent that it's infuriating. Any response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If `wos_report_param.sys_date` is a `TIMESTAMP` (note that it's rather confusing to name a column `sys_date` when there is a `sysdate` function that returns a `DATE`), and assuming that `wos_report_param.sys_date` is a timestamp in the past, your logic can be simplified quite a bit

```
IF( current_timestamp - entrydate > numtodsinterval( validTimeLength, 'second' ) )
THEN
  RETURN true;
ELSE 
  RETURN false;
END IF;
```

If my guess is correct and  `wos_report_param.sys_date` is a timestamp in the past, then the `diffseconds` you are computing will be a negative number which explains why your procedure always returns `false`.  You need to subtract the earlier date from the later date in order to yield a positive rather than a negative interval.  Or you could throw an `abs` around your `diffseconds` calculation.

Comment: After changing my code to implementing your (MUCH) cleaner solution, my report still seems to proceed to show the report, when it should be returning false. The problem is not that it always returns false, but rather that it seems to be always returning TRUE. You were correct though, the subtraction of my dates was done in the opposite order that they should have.

Comment: @KevinCruz - What are the two timestamps when the function returns `true` when you believe it should return `false` or `false` when you believe it should return `true`?  `current_timestamp` returns a `timestamp with time zone` so if `entrydate` has a different implied time zone, that could affect the calculation.

Comment: Upon further experimentation, it appears that as soon as I add this line:  

    `select sys_date into entrydate from wos_report_param where     sequence_num=:SEQUENCENUM and parameter='year';` 

the report stops listening to me. Even when I change the return value to a hard-coded false, it continues to go through. 

`entrydate's date format is: 8/14/2012 4:22:49.687108 PM`
`While current_timestamp is: 8/29/2012 5:08:28.351726 PM -07:00`

Perhaps this is where the problem stems from? What's the easy way to match entrydate's timestamp format?

Comment: @KevinCruz - What do you mean by matching a timestamp format?  If `wos_report_param.sys_date` is a `TIMESTAMP`, there is no format to match.  If the two timestamps are 2 weeks apart, the problem is not one of time zone conversion.  It sounds like your `SELECT INTO` statement is raising an exception.  That would lead me to believe that your query is not returning exactly 1 row.

Comment: In reference to the select into statement, when I run the statement through Toad only one row IS being returned. Clearly it is the select into statement that is breaking the report, but I can't for the life of me figure out why. What I'm really trying to do here is retrieve a timestamp from a table, compare the retrieved timestamp to a `current_timestamp` in format `8/14/2012 4:22:49.687108 PM` , and check to see if it falls within the valid `timelength` of `120 seconds`. Why is it that if I select `current_timestamp from dual` I receive the `-07:00` portion, when I don't in my `sys_date`

Comment: @KevinCruz - `current_timestamp` returns a `timestamp with time zone`. You declared `entrydate` as a `timestamp` so it won't have a time zone. I assume you declared `entrydate` as a `timestamp` because `wos_report_param.sys_date` is a `timestamp` rather than a `timestamp with time zone`. Regardless, the presence or absence of a time zone is not going to affect anything when the difference between the timestamps is 2 weeks. My wager is that the query you're executing in TOAD doesn't match the query you're executing in your trigger probably because `:SEQUENCENUM` isn't what you think it is.